# Prove there are no solutions to the equation $k(2^n-1)=(3^{2q+1}-1)$ where $n,q>1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove there are no solutions to the equation $k(2^n-1)=(3^{2q+1}-1)$  where $n,q>1$.

For a start I reasoned that $n$ had to be odd as otherwise $3|2^n-1$ which was obviously bad.

Furthermore, it is sufficient to prove for $n=p$ where $p$ is a prime as $2^p-1$ is a factor of $2^n-1$ if $p|n$.

Furthermore, I think you can prove that all the divisors of $2^p-1$ are congruent to $1\pmod{p}$ (by cyclotomic polynomials and the fact that $2^p \equiv 2 \pmod{p}$ (Fermat's little theorem)

Also I noticed that if there is one solution for $q$ there are infinitely many. (Not sure if that helps).

Any help would be very much appreciated.